# Why a passive form could not be correct for this sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, transitivity

why do we use an active form of present perfect in the following sentence but we do not use a passive of it i.e, **has been evolved**?

> The island of Mauritius **has evolved** from an agricultural to a
>   semi-industrialized country over the past three decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because to evolve is an intransitive verb, it does not take an object.

You cannot evolve something, something is not evolved by something else.

That also means that a passive form (implying that the evolving is done by something *to* Mauritius) is not an option.

Comment: +.75 *Evolve* may be used transitively: one may *evolve* plans, or solutions, or ideas, and that use will accommodate a passive as well. But this use demands an 'agent', a person or institution actively pursuing an end, which is contrary to the general notion of biological or social evolution.